# create a seamless room

Tags: unity

I'm trying to create the effect of the second picture below where there is no seam between the floor or wall. An effect that is typically used in studios by having a curved wall. This way it looks like the model is standing in an infinite space while still being able to cast a shadow on the floor for example.

[image]

There are probably different ways to create this. But how would you do it? I was thinking of a using a curved wall that starts from the floor and curves up. Then simply use a gradient texture on it. To create the curved wall I was planning to use this package that allows me to use splines directly in unity, instead of creating a curved wall in Blender and then importing it in unity for example.

I haven't bought the package yet because I would like to know if there are any better ways to create something like this. As you see here in the image below there is this gradient background effect. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7038

[image]

Comment: I added some extra info. Hope this helps.

Comment: Use a skybox (sky sphere, really) with a gradient, rather than a nearby model... If there's nothing else in your scene, that should do the trick?

Comment: but how would I make the shadows visible on the ground? I would still need an plane as a floor. that plane would break the smooth gradient transition (I think).

Comment: Ohh so you want the physicality of the floor and wall, but with smooth transition. Makes sense! Splines & curves it is. Why are you reluctant to import from Blender? Sounds like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went for the Blender solution. Modeled a curved wall and imported it into unity. It gave the desired effect.